# why firebase does not let console.log displaying colors?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I use some libes, such as chalk, or boxen, in order to output some logs with colors in the console (server side, via node inside cloud functions). But the colors do not appears. The only colors working in the output, are thoses coming from Firebase. (the ones with the tick, the warn or info icon). Do you know how to hack this ? (i really need my colors in the output)

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you mean without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cloud Functions console is can not currently be customized.  If this is important to you, please [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Comment: I have used ansi colors for the moment : https://github.com/shiena/ansicolor/blob/master/README.md and it works...